# How to set text of asp.net server control in client side via its id?

Tags: asp.net

I have tree textbox inputs in client side and tree aspxtextboxes in server side i want to set text of each server textbox to  related client input in client side as client side values changed but i want to do all in a single method
to do it in separate methods i can use `controlName.SetText("text");`
but i want something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").change(function () {
                //                var servercontrol = document.getElementById((this.name).substring(6));
               //or $("#" + (this.name).substring(6)).SetText("some text");
                servercontrol.SetText(this.value);

            });
```

which makes error.
Thanks in advanced.

Edit: I have to retrieve sender name at client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is in aspx file then you can use server side directive to get client id - for example:

```
$('#<%= MyTextBox.ClientID %>').val("Set this text");
```

Otherwise, you have to somehow pass the control's client id to the relevant script.